# windows phone 8 + Background work app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

i try to programming on my Lumia with windows phone 8.1 in Visual Studio 2013.

Can't find in internet any informations about background working app like skype or facebook apps.

So, i need to do app, what can working when they was closed, can you help me? 
Or give me some links, please, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when your app gets *Suspened* your is stopped by OS and can be even terminated when phone is low on resources ([for more details see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx)). You cannot do much with this, if the user decides to leave your app then it will be suspended.

In WP8.1 [Background Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx) were introduced  - short programs that can run in the bucground and be fired with certain triggers (in Windows Phone 8.0 (also WP8.1 Silverlight) there were [background agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx)). Among those *Tasks* there are also some special ones, for example like [Background Audio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841209.aspx), which allows for continous work but with certain purpose.

So if you need some background work (when your app gets suspended), then you will have to build and register a *Bacground Task* - there are couple of resources in the internet, which may help:

- [MSDN - how to register a Background Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj553413.aspx),
- [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24070323/2681948) - it stays both for Runtime and Silverlight as *Background Tasks* can be used in both systems,
- you may also take a look at [this blog post](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-add-a-backgroundtask/).

Also remember that some apps (Skype for example) are developed by Microsoft or their partners and they can have access to different APIs other that official for average developers.