# BackgroundTaskRegistration internal exception in wp8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, background-task

I don't know how to create background task in WindowsPhone 8.1. [Here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/04/04/windows-phone-8-1-a-universal-background-task.aspx) is a solution I found. But when I rewrited the could, it throw an internal exception at line

```
this.taskRegistration = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Values.First();"
```

Who can tell me why?

The exception as follow

```
System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=-2146233079
Message=Sequence contains no elements
Source=System.Core
StackTrace:
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what exacly causes exception without more code. Maybe you will find more information: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj553413.aspx), [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24076237/2681948), [blog post](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-add-a-backgroundtask/).

Comment: The exception is being thrown, because `Values` doesn't have any element in sequence. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050(v=vs.100).aspx), in particular `Exceptions` section. Instead of `First()`, use `FirstOrDefault()` which won't throw an exception if sequence is empty, but rather will return `null`.