# BackgroundTaskBuilder.Register throws exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I'm trying to register a background task with the *GattCharacteristicNotifictionTrigger* to receive data from a BLE device, but no matter what I do, the app ALWAYS throws an exception when it reached the *.Register()* line. I've referred to numerous guides on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx) and on other places and I believe I'm doing everything that's needed. Below is a checklist highlighting what was needed. I've done nothing more and nothing less as far as the background task goes:

1) Set the declaration for the background task in Package.appxmanifest like so:

```
      <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="AgHost.BackgroundTask">
      <BackgroundTasks>
      <Task Type="systemEvent" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundBLEService.MyBLEService">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <m3:Task Type="gattCharacteristicNotification" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

2) Add a reference to the WinRT project which has the background task in my main app project (which is a Silverlight 8.1 project btw)

3) Create a Run() function within the background service class (which is a sealed, public class) like so:

```
public sealed class MyBLEService: IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        try
        {
            GattCharacteristicNotificationTriggerDetails details = (GattCharacteristicNotificationTriggerDetails)taskInstance.TriggerDetails;
            byte[] ReceivedData = new byte[details.Value.Length];
            DataReader.FromBuffer(details.Value).ReadBytes(ReceivedData);

            foreach(byte b in ReceivedData)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(b.ToString());
                XmlDocument xml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
                xml.SelectSingleNode("/toast/visual/binding/text").InnerText = string.Format("Value Received: " + b.ToString());
                ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(xml);
                ToastNotifier notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
                notifier.Show(toast);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Background service exception");
        }
    }
}
```

4) Register the event from within my main app like so:

```
            GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger trigger = new GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger(thermometerCharacteristic); //thermometerCharacteristic is defined in another block of code
            await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            BackgroundTaskBuilder BLETaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            BLETaskBuilder.Name = "DataReceiveNotifier";
            BLETaskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = "BackgroundBLEService.MyBLEService";
            BLETaskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);
            App.MyBackgroundTask = BLETaskBuilder.Register();
```

5) Make sure the string sequence for the background task entry point *exactly* matches the namespace.classname spelling of the background project. I've checked and double checked the spellings both in the Package.appxmanifest and in my main project where I'm attempting to register the task.

But I'm still getting a first chance exception when the code hits the *.Register()* line. More details about the exception:

- HResult: -2147221164
- Message: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070323/register-background-task-in-silverlight-8-1-app), but it's not definitely answered.

Comment: Is it possible that you can share a sample project with the issue?

Comment: Can you also check if your code runs with different trigger - for example *TimeTrigger*?

Comment: It's now throwing a System.UnauthorizedAccessException on the .Register() line. Apart from adding a declaration of using the timer in Package.appxmanifest, were any other changes required?

Comment: And the entire project is rather large since it has a bunch of audio files in its assets.

Comment: Take a look at [this sample at Github](https://github.com/Romasz/WP81Silverlight-Examples/tree/master/TimeBTask-Silverlight81) - it's simple background taks with Timer. I also get similar exception, when I had bad namespace/class name in entry point and in declarations.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case...

When you use `builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false))` you will need to check `Timer` as well as `System Event` in your `Package.appxmanifest` file. It was working for me.

Comment: I had the opposite problem, kind of -- my TimeTrigger worked unreliably. At some point I added

`new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable)`

to the registration; I'm _guessing_ this is when the unreliability was introduced. At any rate, adding 

`<Task Type="systemEvent" />`

to the manifest fixed the problem, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely your class name at the TaskEntryPoint isnt correct. It's better to use
`BLETaskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(ClassName).FullName` instead of a hardcoded string.

That way if you change the name of the class and you forget to do it somewhere else in your C# code, your code won't compile and it'll be easier to spot because of the error.

Comment: Tried it. Still same exception.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED: The project I was working on was initially pulled from GitHub and targeting Windows Phone 8. Later on I changed it heavily so there were a bunch of unused pages and references, and when I decided to add BLE functionality I retargeted it to Windows Phone 8.1.

But seeing no solution to this problem, I decided to make a last ditch attempt by creating a fresh 8.1 project and copying over all my relevant code from the other project. I made no changes to the code I've pasted above and the background task now runs perfectly.

Just goes to show that retargeted projects don't always work correctly.