# ThreadPoolTimer not run when app is suspended

Tags: timer, win-universal-app

I create a ThreadPoolTimer to refresh my token(which will expire in 12 hours), and the timer is expected to be ticked in 12 hours. However, I put my UWP app in background over 12 hours, and then resume the app, the timer is not ticked even though the token is expired. Seems that when the app is background, the ThreadPoolTimer is also suspended. I tried DispatcherTimer, which is not suspended when the app is in background, however it's only available in UI thread. Is there any replacement Timer in UWP can meet my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior - when the app is suspended, all it's processes are being stopped - [take a look at App's Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle).

Your scenario - to run code in 12h interval, fits *BackgroundTask* with *TimeTrigger*. Take a look [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks) and [there is also a sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-).

Once I've also written [a blog post about running such task](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-add-a-backgroundtask/) - maybe will help. Also take a look at [this answer at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24076237/2681948).