# Background Task does not run in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, background-task

I have a UWP application where I want to add background task support for doing certain things while my application is in background.
I am doing exactly as it is mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task

I have one separate project for Background Tasks and in my package manifest file I have declared that my app uses background tasks (but "timer" task since I am using TimerTrigger). Code:

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder backgroundTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder { Name = "NotificationUpdater", TaskEntryPoint = "NamespaceOfMyBackgroundTaskInterfaceImplementation.BackgroundTask"};

backgroundTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));

BackgroundTaskRegistration backgroundTaskRegistration = backgroundTaskBuilder.Register();
```

Now, when I launch my app (via Visual Studio), and use Lifecycle Events dropdown to suspend my app, it never executes the `Run()` method in the BackgroundTask class (implementation of IBackgroundTask interface).
Code inside BackgroundTask class:

```
namespace NamespaceOfMyBackgroundTaskInterfaceImplementation
{
    public sealed class BackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            //Code to run in the background
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you declared an entry point in manifest file, added a reference in your main project and made your BTask a runtime component? You may also take a look [at the steps here at answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24076237/2681948).

Comment: Yes, I have declared the entrypoint in the manifest file, added a reference in my app project. My BakgroundTask is  Universal Windows class library actually since I am developing a UWP app.

Comment: Ah, I think that's what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Change it to *Windows Runtime Component* and probably will run.

Comment: It does indeed work after changing to Windows Runtime. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out in the conversation, the problem was in wrong declaration of project type. In should be a *Windows Runtime Component*.

For the followers, please take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24076237/2681948), which describes the steps. It answers to *Silverlight 8.1*, but the process and steps are the same in *WinRT* and *UWP*.

Comment: Hey@Romasz just wanted to check if you have any thoughts on this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837912/background-agent-in-uwp

Comment: @AshishAgrawal No - no thoughts on that. Can you say from where you have those information?

Comment: I kind of figured that out by running some validations in both the platforms.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal I would stick to the docs rather than what I've observed when running app myself.

Comment: Yes, but I think they have these constraints in Windows phone 10 as well: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fd5f3fd7-49a9-4b4a-9b7e-13abf03016b1/background-agent-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: I noticed one strange thing about the background agent I implemented. So it all works fine if I use the lifecycle events dropdown to suspend the app and trigger the background task from the dropdown, but if I test it in by closing my app or suspending it, it does not trigger the background agent at all (even if I wait for two long hours).

Comment: @AshishAgrawal Try to stick to [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/guidelines-for-background-tasks).

Comment: Yes I will try this out. Thanks for the guidelines.