# Define Entry Point of a BackgroundTask for UWP

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, background-task

I want to know how can I declarate in the EntryPoint of a Declaration in the manifest file the location of the code to execute as a background task.

I have my code set in a folder called "Models" inside the project, But I don't know how to reffer to this code.
Here you have a picture of it:

[image]

Just in case, here is my code inside the cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace Universal_in_C.Models
{
    public sealed class ExampleBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public async Task ExampleMethodAsync()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Done Exe");
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("TESTING, TESTING LIKE THERE IS NO TOMORROW.");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            await ExampleMethodAsync();
            _deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

And how I call it(I know that I need to change the entry here too);

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var taskRegistered = false;
    var exampleTaskName = "BackgroundTask";

    foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
    {
        if (task.Value.Name == exampleTaskName)
        {
            taskRegistered = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (taskRegistered)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Already Exist");
    }
    else
    {
        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        Debug.WriteLine("Started to Exist");
        builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = "exampleTaskName";
        builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.InternetAvailable, true));
        builder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.UserPresent));
        builder.Register();
    }


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24076237/2681948) will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you are having problems declaring the background task on the manifest file. Based on this, my answer.

1. You need to create a new project that will contain your background tasks. This is necessary in order to correctly [debug them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/launch-resume/debug-a-background-task) later on.
2. Reference the project on your application.
3. Create the task by implementing the [IBackgroundTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224794) interface.
4. Register it via code.
5. Register it on the manifest.

At step number 5, the entry point is always the `{project namespace}.{background task name}`, so for example if you created a project names `BackgroundTasks` with a task `ExampleTask`, the entry point will be: `BackgroundTasks.ExampleTask`

I'll leave for future references a link to the [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/launch-resume/guidelines-for-background-tasks) and [tutorial on how to implement them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task).